# I want to customize MUI Grid height

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui, grid

I'm new to React. I want to limit MUI Grid height.

I divided my project in to 3 parts using MUI grid. I want to limit the height of the page to remove Browser scrollbar. If the content overflow in any grid I want to add custom scrollbar. But I can't Limit the size of my page I used height: 100vh, height: 100%, max-Height: 100vh etc... in css file none of them worked for me. Is it possible?

Comment: add the problematic code to your question

Answer (score 0):

mui grid inherits from its parent so you have to give it a wrapper with styling like this

```
 const ExampleLayout = () => { 
    return (
      <div style={{display:'flex', width:'100%' }}>
       <div style={{display:'flex', flex: '1 1 0%', overflow: 'auto'}}>
        <MuiGrid/>
       </div>
      </div> }
```

or with CSS

```
.top-div{ 
  display:flex;
}
.grid-wrapping-div{
  display:flex; 
  flex:1 1 0%; 
  overflow: auto;
}
```